# Sharing DNA with Capon family.on AncestryDNA?

Tags: england, birth-records, census-records, ancestry.com

My Grand Father, James Alfred Capon, was a [Nurse Child](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3017/19).  He had the family surname on a census. I am in a Family Circle with the family he stayed with.

Does this mean he was their child?

My father and I have the same surname of CAPON and I am asking because I cannot find his birth certificate.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  When say that you are "in a Family Circle with the family he stayed with" do you perhaps mean that you are "in a [**DNA** Circle](https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/How-DNA-Circles-are-created-1460089695851) with **descendants of** the family he stayed with"?  Which census was this in?

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that a family would refer to their own son as a nurse-child, but he might still be a blood relative. The linked question describes all sorts of reasons why someone might be a nurse-child, but if you have a confirmed DNA link to the adoptive family, that suggests a relationship of some sort.

I have an example of a nurse-child in a similar situation.

In the 1911 census he was listed as a "Nurse Child" and had a different surname to the family he was with. (He had their surname in all subsequent records, as do his descendants.) That led to a birth certificate. He was born in the workhouse with a mother named, but no father. His mother's surname turned out to be the same as his adoptive mother's maiden name, and I was able to demonstrate that they were sisters.

So he was raised by his aunt, and in this case his descendants would certainly have DNA matches to his adoptive family.

I think it's worth investigating the adoptive family further - look at their relatives (siblings, cousins...) and see if any registered the birth of a son at around the right time. His birth surname may well have been something other than Capon, which would explain why you haven't found his registration yet.